# Programming Symbols : Instance/Instantiation

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, notation

Is there a generally accepted symbol for indicating instantiation. That is indicating an object is an instance of a class.

My first guess is to use a left arrow with a double or triple line but this seems more like a functional programming symbol, based upon what I've seen of Haskell.

Wikipedia has no examples and a quick google for psuedocode mostly turns up simple functional or procedural algorithms. Object Orientated examples don't seem to feature or do not use any specific symbol.

Comment: This was originally asked on [TeXExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337144/14593)

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Thanks for letting us know about the cross-post.  However, cross-posting isn't allowed.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  I suggest you pick one community where you want the question to appear, and delete the other copy.

Comment: I've decided to give comp sci a shot at answering this first, the TeX Exchange guys seemed to think it was a better fit for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most contexts, objects are values and classes are types, so I would simply use the colon, representing the "has type" relation:

$Object : Class$

That said, this depends on your context, and whether $:$ carries some other meaning. You could also use $\in$, since you can identify a class with the set of objects that are instances of that class.

Comment: Be careful in the presence of subtypes and subclasses -- this might or might not mean what you want it to mean.  Suppose C is a class and D is a subclass of D.  Suppose O is an instance of D.  Then both O : D and O : C would be valid (since O can be validly be given the type C).  The same comments apply to subtyping.  For this reason, it's probably a good idea to define what you mean by your notation explicitly.

Comment: @D.W. I'm a bit rusty on my OO theory. So in your example, if we did `O = new D()`, we would say that `O` is an instance of `D` but not `C`, even though both $O:D$ and $O:C$ hold through subsumption?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit rusty too.  I don't know whether it'd be normal to call `O` an instance of `C` in that case.  I hope someone else here knows more.  Here's some terminology I think I remember seeing in some PL papers: If we declared a variable as as `C x;` and then assigned `x = new D();` I have a recollection that we might say "the runtime type of `x` is `D`" but that "the statically declared type of `x` is `C`" -- the latter is a statement about the declared type of the variable `x`; the former is a statement about the (most-specific) runtime type of the value stored in that variable.

Comment: My actual use case is in documenting test functions in a table, specifically `testIsInstance` and `testNotInstance`. `O:C` and `O:D`would then be valid representations of the former even if D is a subclass of C, and a striked colon could represent the latter. I'm using ∈ for sets. Perhaps `O:(D<C)` or `O:D(C)` could be used to represent the appropriate hierarchy in more explicit cases. It seems odd that there doesn't appear to be a formalized set of symbols/notation.

Comment: Actually I ended up going with `\circ` as `\not:` just looks awful and `\circ`in normal math indicates _function of_ which one could imagine maps to _Instance of_. At a push I suppose one could use `\circ` and `\cdot`as compliments..